# AutoMapper AutoMapperMappingException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, mapping, automapper

I've found some very strange behaviour of AutoMapper.
This simple code

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<MyClass1, MyClass2>(); });
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<MyClass3, MyClass4>(); });

        var dto = new MyClass1();
        Mapper.Map<MyClass1, MyClass2>(dto);
    }
}

public class MyClass1
{
}

public class MyClass2
{
}

public class MyClass3
{
}

public class MyClass4
{
}
```

generates exception:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: MyClass1 -> MyClass2 ConsoleApplication2.MyClass1 ->
>   ConsoleApplication2.MyClass2

but if change order of two initialize lines like this

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<MyClass3, MyClass4>(); });
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<MyClass1, MyClass2>(); });
```

everything is fine. What's wrong? What's going on?

Comment: Don't call `Initialize` twice..... call it once....

Comment: try to use Mapper.CreateMap<> this for map configuration.

Comment: "Don't call Initialize twice..... call it once...." - yes, it works. But if i need initialize at different parts of code, what should i do? I can't use static methods, only instances?

Comment: "try to use Mapper.CreateMap<> this for map configuration" do u mean to use instance instead of  static methods or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, Jimmy *temporarily* moved away from the static stuff in AutoMapper in favour of instance based mapping. However, as Jimmy commented:

> The static mapper is not removed, just the ability to call CreateMap anywhere in the code

The answer to question what is wrong is that you're trying to initialise twice, rather then once.

To answer the next question about how to have different configurations scattered across the code, you use `Profile`

To answer how you configure all of it, please see below:

---

### For AutoMapper 5.1.1

There is a `MapperConfigurationExpression`

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/Configuration/MapperConfigurationExpression.cs

You can pass to the mapper, or `Mapper` takes a `Action<IMapperConfigurationExpression>`.

`IMapperConfigurationExpression` exposes this:

```
void AddProfile(Profile profile)
```

So you can pretty much do the same as below, but register everything against a `IMapper` interface, which is what it seems like `4.2.1` was heading towards.

### For AutoMapper 4.2.1 (Short Intro to Profiles)

Here is an example profile:

```
using AutoMapper;

using TreasuryRecords.Database.Models;
using TreasuryRecords.Requests.Account.Models;

public class AccountMappings : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        this.CreateMap<RegisterDto, Client>()
            .ForMember(x => x.UserName, c => c.MapFrom(x => x.Email));
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how I register my profiles:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

using AutoMapper;

using TreasuryRecords.Requests.Authenticate.Login;

public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Assembly
            .GetExecutingAssembly()
            .RegisterConfigurations();

        typeof(LoginRequest)
            .Assembly
            .RegisterConfigurations();
    }

    public static void RegisterConfigurations(this Assembly assembly)
    {
        var types = assembly.GetTypes();

        var automapperProfiles = types
                                    .Where(x => typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(x))
                                    .Select(Activator.CreateInstance)
                                    .OfType<Profile>()
                                    .ToList();

        // so here you can pass in the instance of mapper
        // I just use the static for ease
        automapperProfiles.ForEach(Mapper.Configuration.AddProfile);
    }
}
```

This is how I add it to DI:

```
public static void RegisterAutoMapper(this IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType<IMapper>(new InjectionFactory(_ => Mapper.Instance));
}
```

I'm using unity here, but it is pretty simple, just register `Mapper.Instance` against the interface `IMapper`.

Then I inject `IMapper` and use it like so:

```
this.mapper.Map<Client>(message.RegistrationDetails);
```

Comment: - yes, it works. But if i need initialize at different parts of code, what should i do? I can't use static methods, only instances?

Comment: AutoMapper utilises instance configuration. You use the AutoMapper Profiles. Then you can use an extension method to load all the profiles up...

Comment: Great! But there is no Mapper.Configuration.AddProfile in 5.1.1 AutoMapper. Is it was deleted or u use some extension?

Comment: Updated again, for `5.1.1`

Comment: yes, and i can can create new configuration with IMapperConfigurationExpression.AddProfile, but i can't apply it to static Mapper. I can only create instance of new configuration and new Mapper

Comment: Yes, they removed static mapper from the latest AutoMapper

Comment: @TimurLemeshko I just reword, and re-jigged my answer so that is fits your question better, and makes more sense. See if it is any better for you.

Comment: The static mapper is *not* removed, just the ability to call CreateMap anywhere in the code. You just need one Mapper.Initialize at the startup of your application.

I took the static stuff out for a little bit, but put it back, but just in favor of a very explicit configuration step. All the instance stuff is still there for that that need it though.

Comment: @JimmyBogard yeah no definitely my bad, I misread the source code.... will change